# How to solve a set of 3 nonlinear equations (lines in space)

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I would like to calculate the following:

There are 3 points in space of which the coordinates are known: 
$C(a,b,c),
M(d,e,f),
A(g,h,i)$

Each point is a starting point of a line with a certain length. These lengths are known: $|CB|=l1,\,    |MB|=l2,\,    |AB|=l3$

There exist 2 possible points (B1 and B2) in space where the end points of these lines coincide. So what I would like to calculate are the coordinates of these 2 points.

The set of equations looks like this:
$$(a-x)²+(b-y)²+(c-z)² = l1^2\\
(d-x)²+(e-y)²+(f-z)² = l2^2\\
(g-x)²+(h-y)²+(i-z)² = l3^2$$

B(x,y,z) = ?

Thank you in advance for any hint to solve this problem

Comment: Equation 1 minus Equation 2 is a plane, P1.  Equation1 minus Equation3 is a plane, P2.  The intersection of P1 and P2 is a line.  Write the line with one parameter.  (x,y,z)=(m+pt,n+qt,r+st).  Feed those into equation 1 to get a quadratic.

Comment: The system can also have infinite or no solutions

Comment: I deducted equation 1 with 2 and equation 1 with 3. From the 2 resulting equations I calculated the cross product with the following result:  -4bi - 4ce + 4ei +4bf + 4ch - 4fh    /   -4cg - 4af + 4fg + 4ai + 4cd - 4di    /   -4ah - 4bd + 4dh + 4bg + 4ae - 4eg   I don't see how you can write this line with 1 parameter.